# Suggestions for information visualization using flash or javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, visualization, diagram

I remember looking at a couple information visualizations tool a while back.
One was written in flash and the other in Javascript.

They both allowed you put notes in "bubbles" and then link them to other "bubbles".

Clicking on an existing bubble brought it to the front and rearranged others around it.

The JS one was particularly interesting as it worked as a standalone app on your local file system.

Now i cant remember the magical google words to find them.

Does any know of the tools i am talking about or know what this form of information diagramming is called?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) for data visualization in Flash.

It's adapted from [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/), a data visualization toolkit for Java.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it

http://phasetwo.org/post/a-better-tag-cloud.html

Answer (score 0):

Infoviz for Javascript seems to be nice too:
http://thejit.org/